# To insert values into database using jquery ajax in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In the below code i am trying to insert values into Database using jquery ajax.In my case i am calling the jquery ajax on button click .But it is not calling the webmethod.Pls help me to rectify this issue.

UnitDetails.aspx

```
  <script type="text/JavaScript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
 function MyFunction() {

              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",

                  url: "UnitDetails.aspx/InsertData",
                  data: "{'UnitType':'" + $("#<%=txtUnitTypeName.ClientID%>").val() + "','UnitTypeCode':'" + $("#<%=txtUnitTypeShortCode.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  async: "true",
                  cache: "false",
                  success: function (msg) {
                      alert("Success");
                      // On success                 
                  },
                  Error: function (x, e) {
                      alert("Fail");
                      // On Error
                  }
              });
          }  
<input name="data[UnitType][Name]" type="text" class="autofocus"maxlength="255" id="txtUnitTypeName" runat="server" />

<input name="data[UnitType][ShortCode]" type="text"  maxlength="5" id="txtUnitTypeShortCode"    runat="server" />



[WebMethod]
        public static void InsertData(string UnitType, string Code)
        {
            try
            {
                MastersClient Uinsert = new MastersClient();
                Dictionary<string, string> UnitVal = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                UnitVal.Add("UnitTypeName", UnitType.ToString());
                UnitVal.Add("UnitTypeShortCode", Code.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string strMsg = "Error message : " + Environment.NewLine + "Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + Environment.NewLine + "Error : " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine;
                Logger objErrorHandler = new Logger();
                objErrorHandler.MsgType = MessageType.MailAndEventLog;
                objErrorHandler.RaiseError(strMsg, ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your url address, maybe it should looks like that:

```
~/UnitDetails.aspx/InsertData
```

or

```
~/UnitDetails/InsertData/
```

and check data you are passing through, try to pass static data without extracting value by jQ maybe there is some error. Sth like that:

```
{'UnitType': 'type', 'UnitTypeCode': 'typeCode'}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's your solution

```
     data: "{'UnitType':'" + $("#<%=txtUnitTypeName.ClientID%>").val() + "',
'UnitTypeCode':'" + $("#<%=txtUnitTypeShortCode.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
```

your second argument in your posted data is `UnitTypeCode`

while on your service your second argument is `code` which is wrong it should be same

```
public static void InsertData(string UnitType, string Code)
```

should be

```
public static void InsertData(string UnitType, string UnitTypeCode)
```

hope that helps !